# sharepoint powershell custom sort order

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have a Metadata like this

```
Demo --> Group
 OrgDemo --> Termset
  Demo1 --> Term
      A -->Level1
        A1-->Level2
        B1
        c2
           c21-->Level3
           c22
              c221-->Level4
              D223
     B
        B1
        B2
        B3
             B21
             B23
```

The Metadata is already there and the sorting is done by Sharepoint automatically. Now i want to write to Powershell to read from the XMl file and apply the customsort order for example in the XMl file the sort order is like this B1, A1.

I have already started writing the powershell script. I have applied the customsorder for level1 and if there is more levels how to do it any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the term's in each level - then set the sort order for those - commit changes and move to the next level - do the same

Example -

```
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "Your Site Path"
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Your Term Store Name"]
if($termStore -ne $null){                     
    $group = $termStore.Groups["Demo"]
    if($group -ne $null){                         
        $termSet = $group.TermSets["OrgDemo"]
        $subTermSet1 = $termSet["Demo1"]
        $aTerm = $subTermSet1["A"]
        $bTerm = $subTermSet1["B"]

        $customSortOrder = $aTerm.ID.ToString() + ":" + $bTerm.ID.ToString(); 
        $subTermSet1.CustomSortOrder = $customSortOrder 
    }
}
$termStore.CommitAll();
```